# Why is $(x_1, y_1)\oplus(x_2, y_2)=(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)$, $k\cdot(x_1, y_1)=(kx_1,y_1)$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

On R2, define the operations of addition and scalar
multiplication as follows:

$$(x_1, y_1)\oplus(x_2, y_2)=(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)$$

$$k\cdot(x_1, y_1)=(kx_1,y_1).$$

Why is this a vector space?

I checked the solutions and it says that all axioms pass. I found that all axioms except 1 (Distributive property of scalar multiplication over scalar addition) pass.

This is what the solutions say about the latter axiom:

[image]

I however found that it did NOT pass. My work:

Let $r$, $s$ be scalars, and $v=(x,y)$.

1. $(r+s)\cdot v = (r+s)\cdot (x,y) = ((r+s)x,y)$.
2. $(r\cdot v) + (s\cdot v) = (r\cdot (x,y)) + (s\cdot (x,y)) = (rx,y) + (sx,y) = (rx+sx, y+y) = (rx+rs, 2y)$.

So $(r+s)\cdot v\neq (r\cdot v) + (s\cdot v)$.

Comment: Multiplying by the scalar $k=0$ does not give the zero element of your group. So not a vector space. There probably is a typographical error in your source.

Comment: Your work is correct, and the solution isn’t.